# How to set a stream as flow target using java RTC api?

Tags: java, rtc

I use below code to create a workspace :

```
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.IProgressMonitor;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.NullProgressMonitor;
import com.ibm.team.repository.client.ITeamRepository;
import com.ibm.team.repository.client.ITeamRepository.ILoginHandler;
import com.ibm.team.repository.client.ITeamRepository.ILoginHandler.ILoginInfo;
import com.ibm.team.repository.client.TeamPlatform;
import com.ibm.team.repository.common.TeamRepositoryException;
import com.ibm.team.scm.client.IWorkspaceConnection;
import com.ibm.team.scm.client.IWorkspaceManager;
import com.ibm.team.scm.client.SCMPlatform;
import com.ibm.team.scm.common.IFlowTable;

public class RTCFirst {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String repositoryURI = "https://rtc.domain.com/jazz";
        String userId = "myid";
        String password = "****";

        IProgressMonitor monitor = new NullProgressMonitor();
        try {
            ITeamRepository repo = logIntoTeamRepository(repositoryURI,
                        userId, password, monitor);


            IWorkspaceManager wm = SCMPlatform.getWorkspaceManager(repo);
            IWorkspaceConnection workspace = wm.createWorkspace(repo.loggedInContributor(), "Example Workspace", "Description", monitor);

            IFlowTable ift = workspace.getFlowTable().getWorkingCopy();

        } catch (TeamRepositoryException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private static ITeamRepository logIntoTeamRepository(String repositoryURI,
            String userId, String password, IProgressMonitor monitor)
            throws TeamRepositoryException {
        System.out.println("Trying to log into repository: " + repositoryURI);
        TeamPlatform.startup();
        ITeamRepository teamRepository = TeamPlatform
            .getTeamRepositoryService().getTeamRepository(repositoryURI);
        teamRepository.registerLoginHandler(new LoginHandler(userId, password));
        teamRepository.login(monitor);
        System.out.println("Login succeeded.");
        return teamRepository;
    }

    private static class LoginHandler implements ILoginHandler, ILoginInfo {

        private String fUserId;
        private String fPassword;

        private LoginHandler(String userId, String password) {
            fUserId = userId;
            fPassword = password;
        }

        public String getUserId() {
            return fUserId;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return fPassword;
        }

        public ILoginInfo challenge(ITeamRepository repository) {
            return this;
        }
    }

}
```

I think I need to populate the IFlowTable with the stream I want to flow to ? If so how can this be achieved ? I can use below code to find the stream  :

```
IWorkspaceHandle iwh = (IWorkspaceHandle) findConnectionByName(repo , "mystream" , 1 , monitor).get(0);


private static List findConnectionByName(
        ITeamRepository teamRepository, String name, int kind,
        IProgressMonitor monitor) throws TeamRepositoryException {
    IWorkspaceManager wm = SCMPlatform.getWorkspaceManager(teamRepository);
    IWorkspaceSearchCriteria criteria = IWorkspaceSearchCriteria.FACTORY
            .newInstance().setKind(kind);
    if (name != null) {
        criteria.setExactName(name);
    }
    List<IWorkspaceHandle>workspaces= wm.findWorkspaces(criteria,
            Integer.MAX_VALUE, monitor);
    return workspaces;
}
```

But once I've found the stream how do I add it as flow target ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

don't know if you still need the answer, but I use below code to add a stream (lv1Stream) as flow target of another stream (lv2Stream):

```
        IFlowTable flowTable = lv2Stream.getFlowTable().getWorkingCopy();
        flowTable.addDeliverFlow(lv1Stream.getResolvedWorkspace(), repo.getId(),
            repo.getRepositoryURI(), null, lv1Stream.getDescription());
        IFlowEntry flowNode =
            flowTable.getDeliverFlow(lv1Stream.getResolvedWorkspace());
        flowTable.setDefault(flowNode);
        flowTable.setCurrent(flowNode);
        lv2Stream.setFlowTable(flowTable, null);
```